# How to better structure variations for Ecommerce site

Tags: django, e-commerce

I am working on an e-commerce application in Django. It allows for product variations. My first impulse has been to go with multi-table inheritance, where variants have their own table different from the main product table. Both of these inherit an abstract table, so they share common properties. Then in the frontend, implicitly place the main product as the first variation in the variation list.
[image]

The thing I am struggling with deciding whether to duplicate main product as variant like in the Amazon custom implementations of variations, as shown in this image:
[image]

The primary main product always seems to be the first expected product.
But clicking on that, you see that the circled label(color) in the above image, also changes, in this case `01-black`.

My question is, is Amazon duplicating the main product as a variation too? Which means, it will have it's specific features like the color name. That would mean duplication.

If in case then that Amazon is implicitly displaying the main product as the first variation, how come it has unique property values like the color name ````01-black``?